# XAMARIN Remove item from listview with menuItem

Tags: listview, xamarin

Im trying to remove an item within a Listview with a menuItem. But cant seem to get the item to delete. can anyone see whats wrong ? Am i binding wrong in the menuItem?

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="true" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Product}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

xaml.cs

```
  private void MainPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // feedback popup box
             var product = MainPicker.Items[MainPicker.SelectedIndex];
             DisplayAlert(product, "Layer added to calculation list", "OK");
            // if selected add to list          
            if (null != product)
            {
                LayersClass layer = new LayersClass();
                layer.Product = product;
                listProducts.Add(layer);
            }        
        }

        private void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var menuItem = ((MenuItem)sender);
            var product = ( TYPE?)menuItem.CommandParameter; //unsure of type 

            listProducts.Remove(layer);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
 private async void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var menuItem = ((MenuItem)sender);           
            var answer = await DisplayAlert("Are you sure?", null, "Yes", "No");

            if (answer)
            {
                listProducts.Remove((LayersClass)menuItem.CommandParameter);
            }
        }
```